# What is the equivalent of dm_os_volume_stats in SQL Server 2008 R2 in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

`sys.dm_os_volume_stats` was introduced in SQL Server 2008 R2 but not available in SQL Server 2008.

Is custom script the only option or are there any other system views that offer similar functionality?

Comment: Volume stats offer informationa about drive on which data file resides yes there are ways to get this INFO. What is your exact requirement

Comment: Need to generate a report with columns - DB Name, Size of DB, Size of Transaction Log, Drive on which it is stored, Total drive space, Available free space

Comment: Look at sys.master_files and xp_fixed drives. I know you are competant enough to write your own query

Comment: Probably this can help you http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/90392/

Answer (score 0):

Custom script is about all I can think of for 2008.  If you have the ability to execute xp_cmdshell, I would probably do something like this...

```
DECLARE @recid         INT
       ,@workstring    VARCHAR(8000)
       ,@parsearrayxml XML
       ,@vexec_str     VARCHAR(8000)

-- Create table variable to hold drive size info
DECLARE @drives TABLE (
   [RecID]             TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY -- Record ID 
  ,[Drive]             VARCHAR(10)                       -- Drive letter
  ,[Size]              BIGINT NULL                       -- Drive size
   )

-- Create table variable for xp_cmdshell output
DECLARE @xp_cmdshell_output TABLE (
   [output]            VARCHAR(8000) NULL                -- Raw text returned from xp_cmdshell execution
   )

INSERT INTO @xp_cmdshell_output ([output])
   EXEC [master].[dbo].[xp_cmdshell] N'FSUTIL FSINFO DRIVES'
IF (SELECT COUNT(1) 
       FROM @xp_cmdshell_output 
       WHERE [output] = 'The FSUTIL utility requires that you have administrative privileges.') > 0
  RAISERROR ('SQL Server Service account not an admin on this computer.', 11, 1);
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT @workstring = [output] 
      FROM @xp_cmdshell_output 
      WHERE [output] LIKE 'Drives:%'
   DELETE FROM @xp_cmdshell_output
   SELECT @workstring = REPLACE(@workstring, 'Drives', '')
   SELECT @workstring = REPLACE(@workstring, ':', '')
   SELECT @workstring = REPLACE(@workstring, ' ', '')
   IF CHARINDEX(CHAR(0), @workstring) != 0
      SELECT @workstring = REPLACE(@workstring, CHAR(0), ',')
END
SELECT @parsearrayxml = CAST(
                             ('<X>'
                              + REPLACE(@workstring
                                       ,'\'
                                       ,'</X><X>')
                              + '</X>')
                              AS XML)
INSERT INTO @drives ([Drive])
   SELECT LTRIM(N.value('.', 'VARCHAR(4000)'))
      FROM @parsearrayxml.nodes('X') AS T(N)
      WHERE ASCII(LTRIM(N.value('.', 'VARCHAR(4000)'))) != 0

      -- Get size for each drive
      SELECT @recid = 1
      WHILE @recid <= (SELECT MAX([RecID]) FROM @drives)
      BEGIN
         SELECT @workstring = ''
               ,@vexec_str = 'EXEC [master].[dbo].[xp_cmdshell] ' 
                           + QUOTENAME('FSUTIL VOLUME DISKFREE ' 
                                + [Drive] 
                                + ':'
                             ,CHAR(39))
            FROM @drives
            WHERE [RecID] = @recid
         INSERT INTO @xp_cmdshell_output ([output])
            EXEC (@vexec_str)
         SELECT @workstring = [output] 
            FROM @xp_cmdshell_output 
            WHERE [output] LIKE '%Total # of bytes%'
         IF @workstring IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@workstring) > 0
         BEGIN
            SELECT @workstring = LTRIM(
                                       SUBSTRING(@workstring
                                                ,CHARINDEX(':'
                                                          ,@workstring
                                                          ) + 1
                                                ,LEN(@workstring)
                                                )
                                       )
            SELECT @workstring = LEFT(@workstring, LEN(@workstring)-1)
            UPDATE @drives 
               SET [Size] = (CONVERT(BIGINT, @workstring)/1024)/1024 
               WHERE [RecID] = @recid
         END
         ELSE 
         DELETE
            FROM @drives 
            WHERE [RecID] = @recid
         DELETE FROM @xp_cmdshell_output
         SELECT @recid = @recid + 1
      END
SELECT * FROM @drives
```

You may have to debug my code a little but the concept should get you going in the right direction.

Cheers,
Ken